# Xamarin forms app crashes for Arabic in iOS 16 beta

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, arabic-support, ios16

Xamarin forms-based application crashes in **iOS 16 beta** for Arabic languages when there are two lines in the resx string. Also, it will crash if we apply "\n" in the code when binding to XAML file.
example

```
<data name="some_key" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>هذا الإصدار من نوع ألفا!
.استخدام هذا التطبيق مخصص لغرض الاختبار فقط</value>
 </data>
```

Used resx in XAML file like below

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                   Text="{localization:Translate some_key}">
                                   
</Label>
```

Is this a problem with Xamarin forms or iOS?

Comment: Does it also fail in iOS 15?  Id suggest filing a bug with Xamarin

Comment: No . iOS 15 it is working fine. Issue is in iOS 16

Comment: Then you should file a bug report

Comment: yes submitted bug report https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15535

Answer (score 0):

The actual suggested workaround is: If we remove the ar from info.plist Localizations then it will not crash for new line

Comment: you can remove info.plist entry it will automatically pick the Arabic resources. but "ar" is required in info.plist for the system permission strings translations